# Order custom fields alphabetically

Tags: custom-field, order

I've been trying to order the custom fields alphabetically, but I can't get the ordered list I want... this is the code I'm using:

```
<?php 
        $vMarca = get_field('tienda_marcas'  , false, false);
        $post_objects = get_posts(array(
            'post__in'   => $vMarca,
            'order'   => 'ASC'  ,
            'orderby'   => 'title'  
        ));

        if($vMarca)
        {
            echo '<ul>' ;
            foreach($vMarca as $post_objects)
            {
                echo '<li>'  . $post_objects . '</li>' ;
            }
            echo '</ul>' ;
        }

        ?>
```

I need the custom fields to be ordered alphabetically.

Comment: So What's output ?

Comment: You are using the $post_objects variable in 2 different contexts here. Also, what is get_field? That's not a native WP function.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answers! Sorry if i didn't specify the problem... i'm using Advanced Custom Fields and the output is this: http://grab.by/kOz8... 
As you can see, the item "Otra Marca" is at the end, but it should be listed alphabetically... that is the problem

Comment: also, "get_field" it's from Advanced Custom Fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to output the wrong stuff. You've ordered the `$post_objects`, not the `$vMarca`. Try using the `$post_objects` variable for your `if` and `foreach` statements thus:

```
<?php 
    $vMarca = get_field('tienda_marcas'  , false, false);
    $post_objects = get_posts(array(
        'post__in'   => $vMarca,
        'order'   => 'ASC'  ,
        'orderby'   => 'title'  
    ));

    if($post_objects)
    {
        echo '<ul>' ;
        foreach($post_objects as $post)
        {
            setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        }
        echo '</ul>' ;

    ?>
```

Comment: Great Answer! but i haven't been clear with the problem. I assume that i'm calling the wrong stuff. Let me rephrase it: i have installed Advanced Custom Field and i'm calling custom fields in a post in this way: http://grab.by/kOGO, which outpost this way: http://grab.by/kOHi. As you can see, the resultant list is not ordered alphabetically, that is my question.

Comment: Right - I believe I understand you. What I'm saying is that it looks like, since you were looping through `$vMarca` which was unordered, you would want to switch to looping through `$post_objects` which you *had* ordered. Did you try my version?

Comment: Any progress, @JuanPabloContreras?